# Submitting Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that has required fields and it will not submit the form unless you fill in the required items, it works in google chrome and firefox but it does not work in safari. Why is that and does anyone now how to make it where the form can not be submitted unless the items are filled out that are required. Here is just a small amount of the code.

```
<form method="post" action="##" name="aForm" id="addClientForm" class="">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="clientAdd">
    <input type="hidden" name="datasource" value="<cfoutput>#request.dsn#</cfoutput>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Active" value="1">

    <div style="float:left;" class="formContent470">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
        <th colspan="" style="text-align:left;">Add Client</th>
        </tr>
            <tr><cfoutput>
                <td>
                Contact
                    <span style="color:red">*</span>
                <input type="Text" name="Contact" value="" required="Yes" message="Contact is required" maxLength="75" class="inputText430"> 
                </td>
            </tr>
```

And here is the jquery code that should make it work I believe.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addClientForm").validate();
        rules: {
            Contact: {
                required: true
            },
            ClientName: {
                required: true
            },
            ClientLogin: {
                required: true
            },
               ClientPassword: {
                required: true
            },
            Email: {
                required: true
            }
        },
});
```

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you include your <src> link tag to the jquery plugin (validate) before jquery itself ?

Comment: Hi the javascript you have provided is invalid. can you provide a Fiddle.

Comment: yes i have the <src> links tag above the jQuery

Comment: you have the form's opening tag right? cause this: `form method="post" action="##" name="aForm" id="addClientForm" class="">` has a syntax error

Comment: In the code I have a < it was just missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good way to make it work with all browsers.

```
 function hasHtml5Validation () {
    return typeof document.createElement('input').checkValidity === 'function';
   }

 if (hasHtml5Validation()) {
     $('.addClientForm').submit(function (e) {
       if (!this.checkValidity()) {
            e.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass('invalid'); 
      $('#status').html('invalid');
   } else {
      $(this).removeClass('invalid');
      $('#status').html('submitted');
    }
 });
} 
<p>Status: <span id="status">Unsubmitted</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code has error sintax.. I put the params rules on the method validate. On your example the param you put out of method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addClientForm").validate({
        rules: {
            Contact: {
                required: true
            },
            ClientName: {
                required: true
            },
            ClientLogin: {
                required: true
            },
               ClientPassword: {
                required: true
            },
            Email: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use required attribute in HTML5 to make a field mandatory to be filled. no javascript needed.

```
<input type='text' required name='surName'>
```

Comment: Im not sure if i follow I believe I already have it required in the code above I have it sent to required would this be any different